# How to convert pandas dataframe to HEC DSS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe time series data and I am looking for a way to convert and save it as HEC-DSS file using Python. Is there a library that can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The following page provides  you with the libraries available for managing DSS files using Python:
https://github.com/topics/hec-dss

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.